# Expandable WordPress content (text) inside a post

Tags: custom-post-types, content, the-content

I've created a CPT in my WordPress site. In this CPT I have the content element (which is the default WP content) and want to make it expandable, I mean, while viewing the CPT I want it to only display a few lines of text until you press the view full content or something similar, all this inside the post view. Like in the image below:

[image: Expandable WordPress content inside a post]

Comment: you could simply achieve this any jquery.

Comment: @TheMagentoKid Please, could you tell me the word to search for an example or the link to one? I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following WordPress Plugin, which has plenty of options to customize: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-collapse-o-matic/

Answer (score 0):

There might be two reasons for your problem

1. You are using `<!--more-->`  tag inside your content . If so then remove it.
2. While querying  post you are using `the_excerpt` method , if so then change it to `the_content` .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained very well my question. I am trying to put the see more inside the post.